# Can someone use https for any domain?

Tags: http, https

Let us suppose we have a website `http://www.example.com` and we do not have any website where we dont have any secure site so no such site exist `https://www.example.com`

Some How it is possible someone else can use same domain name which i have and run parallel `https://www.example.com`

**EDIT:-**

Now see one live example

Please open this link https://www.lpu.in/frmLoginAccounts.aspx and main website is http://www.lpu.in/index.php

Can someone tell me `https` used in this website is fraud or someone hacked this website?

Answer (score 1):

No someone else can not take your reserved domain(A-Record), but you can run virtual hosts on your apache server, one that listens to HTTPS(Port 443) and one that listens to HTTP(Port 80). Both can refer to the same directory on your webserver, whereas the HTTPS host configures certificates additionally.

Here is a link to that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it's totally not possible. The domain name (www.example.com) is resolved to an IP address before the HTTP/HTTPS request, therefore they both point to the same Web server.

**EDIT after original question was edited**

when you try to reach www.lpu.in, the first thing your OS does is resolving its domain name in a numeric IP address:

```
$ host www.lpu.in
www.lpu.in has address 173.244.171.162
```

there's absolutely no difference in trying to reach the machine with HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

Therefore, i'm confident that **someone hacked into your server**.

The behaviour you report is possible because Apache has two separate configuration for HTTP and HTTPS, and serves different pages from each if one (you or an hacker) configures it for this purpose.

You should look at the Apache configuration, HTTPS section in particular, to understand what's the DocumentRoot for https virtualhosts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a SSL purchased on your hosting? if you have you can just install and configure on the server and then add an htaccess on the root directory of site with the following code:
**FOR Linux based Hosting:**
htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Windows & Plesk:**
Using the following code in your web.config file automatically redirects visitors to the HTTPS version of your site:

```
<configuration><system.webServer><rewrite> <rules><rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="(.*)" /> <conditions> <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" /></conditions> <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" /></rule> </rules></rewrite></system.webServer></configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you have a broken **SSL** on your site. it is not hacked in my point of view. domain name server cannot be hacked at all. please check check you `htaccess` file if you using Linux hosting or check `webconfig` file if you are on windows hosting. there will any rule defile there so you site is running in both cases. either with `https://` but it is not showing any content of the site so it is broke. or without `https://` that is good so it is showing site contents.

Answer (score 0):

No they dont hacked you. Do you have a webhoster or is this your own server? If you have a webhoster, then they provide you HTTPS with a trustworthy certificate, because my browser says that the certificate is trustworhy, so the Certificate Authority(CA) confirmed the servers identitiy.Otherwise deactivate the HTTPS-Service on your webserver, while you close the listening port(f.e 443).

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: No its not my website, i have done some transaction(Fee Submission)  But now they r telling we dont have any online Payment system. Now i am bit confuse is this website hack or they are telling lie.One thing i want to tell you if you will registration number they are giving user information as well,if it is hacked they hacked Database also and organization have no any knowledge its not possible.